# What is the difference between iptables -s and iptables-save

Tags: iptables

`iptables -S` prints one set of rules, but `iptables-save` prints a superset with a bunch of additional rules. What is the difference? And why doesn't `iptables -S` print the additional rules?

For example, `iptables -S` does not print the rule that alters the source address for SMTP (port 25) packets over the Wireguard interface (wg0) (`-A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.2`) but `iptables-save` does print that rule? I would have guessed that `iptables -S` maybe only prints one chain, but `iptables -h` says:

```
  --list-rules -S [chain [rulenum]]
                Print the rules in a chain or all chains
```

... which seems to imply it will print all chains when given no chain argument.

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sat Jan 30 06:47:36 2021
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [175762948:152635787911]
:INPUT ACCEPT [85129338:67722036020]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [90631707:84913651708]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [43631301:2479371699]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [134263118:87393032790]
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2/0xffffffff
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2/0xffffffff
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jan 30 06:47:36 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sat Jan 30 06:47:36 2021
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [367:62684]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [10426:4247532]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [50809:2739507]
:f2b-sshd - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp2s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp2s0 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i enxa0cec802c711 -o enp2s0 -j DROP
-A f2b-sshd -s 200.140.81.94/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 177.92.35.201/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 94.43.219.173/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 14.228.195.50/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 66.96.232.50/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 71.217.140.138/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 14.249.54.134/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 201.209.161.174/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 174.30.109.183/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 71.217.167.42/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 116.193.139.76/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 41.89.234.2/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 182.71.223.194/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 173.202.19.15/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 180.112.138.132/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jan 30 06:47:36 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sat Jan 30 06:47:36 2021
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [444244:60896263]
:INPUT ACCEPT [168098:15673985]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [120570:8875499]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [113904:8359713]
-A POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.2
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jan 30 06:47:36 2021
```

vs

```
iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): option "-s" requires an argument
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
root@sputnik:/home/nathan# iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp2s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp2s0 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i enxa0cec802c711 -o enp2s0 -j DROP
-A f2b-sshd -s 200.140.81.94/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 177.92.35.201/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 94.43.219.173/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 14.228.195.50/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 66.96.232.50/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 71.217.140.138/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 14.249.54.134/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 201.209.161.174/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 174.30.109.183/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 71.217.167.42/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 116.193.139.76/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 41.89.234.2/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 182.71.223.194/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 173.202.19.15/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 180.112.138.132/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -j RETURN
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Anyways, I've always used `iptables-save`, so you could too.

Comment: I could, but I've been trying to debug some rules, and they don't show up in iptables -S, but they do show up in iptables-save, so it seems like understanding that might be a good step towards debugging my rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RTFM (read the fine manual):

`man iptables`:

> -S, --list-rules [chain]
> Print all rules in the selected chain.  If no chain is selected,
> all chains are printed like iptables-save. Like every other ipt‐
> ables command, it applies to the specified table (filter is  the
> default).
> :

So the point seems to be that the output is restricted to the **filter** table.

Whereas **iptable-save** dumps the whole set of rules in a format suitable for the classic config file.

`man iptable-save`

> ```
>  -t, --table tablename
> ```

```
          restrict output to only one table. If the kernel  is  configured
          with  automatic  module loading, an attempt will be made to load
          the appropriate module for that  table  if  it  is  not  already
          there.
          If not specified, output includes all available tables.
```

Note the **all available tables** as default setting here.

I looked this up on CentOS 7.

Comment: `RTFM` vs `seems to be` - your selection of words is not exactly appropriate. Also, it's never been "fine" but whatever.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov the seems to be was before I read the next man page. And the other meaning of f - well that is well known... ;-)